# How to get rid of unwanted margin of DatePicker widget (Android)?

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker, android-framelayout

I am starting to learn how to develop android apps, more precisely I in trying to make an activity which host a single fragment (that extends DialogFragment) which in turn host a DatePicker Widget. I would like that DatePicker fill all screen width.

The problem is that for an unknown reason it puts a margin in the right of the screen (I want to get rid of the blank space).

This is what i get:

[image: android activity screenshot]

This is DatePicker layout:

```
<DatePicker
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/dialog_date_date_picker"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

This is the activity's layout that host the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

And this is the fragment code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Notice that I don't want to use '**onCreateDialog**', in this particular case I want to use '**onCreateView**'.